# The directory when you install TeXnicCenter

Tags: miktex, texniccenter, acrobat

My whole problem started when I upgraded Adobe Reader to the version DC, it crashed down my LaTeX, I replaced the DC version by the older one.

I remove MiKTeX and TeXnicCenter and installed them again, I kept everything by default, now when I open TeXnicCenter for the first time it asked me about the directory so I put `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin` but it keeps give me the following error message

> "The application "Latex" has not been found in the directory of your tex-distribution"

What is the problem?

Comment: Without some specific detail such as there erro messages it i impossible to answer this.

Comment: Tried other pdf viewers to check if the problem is about texniccenter or miktex?

Comment: The error message says exactly the following: The application "Latex" has not been found in the directory of your tex-distribution

Comment: If you go to Build->Define Output Profiles.. the path to (La)TeX compiler should specify which version  (e.g. pdflatex.exe) to run, depending on which option is selected (e.g. LaTeX=>PDF).  Use the (...) button to browse.  BTW, my path includes a \x64\ after bin.

Comment: Ok, I got the directory problem solved... now I got another problem, I compiled a simple latex file it works very well, then another one it gives 3 errors: the first says..fancyhdr.sty not found...

Comment: well I download the fancyhdr.sty package but still give me the same error, I put the package with folder tex inside the folder miktex 2.9!

Answer (score 1):

The best practice to install MiKTeX, TeXnicCenter and Adobe or better SumatraPDF do the following:

1. Download the installer program for MiKTeX (I suggest the complete installation, so use net installer to avoid missing packages like your `fancyhdr.sty`!)
2. Install MiKTeX
3. Download SumatraPDF and install it. SumatraPDF has not to be closed while compiling a new pdf file (Acrobat has to be closed!).
   Alternative: install Acrobat Reader ...
4. Download the current installer for TeXnicCenter
5. Install TeXnicCenter.  In this order TeXnicCenter is able to find out that MiKTeX is installed and does a lot of configuration things by its own ... That solves for example your problem with the path ... While configuration you are asked to search/add the path for SumatraPDF.

To install new packages to MiKTeX please do only use the MiKTeX package manager for that, this program is desiged to do adding packages for you.  You can choose the new needed packages from a list of available packages ...